# Параллельные потоки, QThread

Tags: c++, qt, многопоточность

Я новичок в QT,ранее почти не работал с потоками, хотелось бы навести справки как правильно пользоваться потоками,параллельно, прочитал достаточно много, каша в голове, усвоить пока не получается...

Вот пример, есть класс identificator, .h:

```
class identificator:public QObject {
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    identificator();
    virtual ~identificator();
private:
    int id;
private slots:
    void printID();
public:
    void setID(int i);
    int getID();
signals:
    void finished();
};
```

.cpp:

```
#include "identificator.h"
#include <stdio.h>

identificator::identificator() {
    id=0;
}

identificator::~identificator() {
    // TODO Auto-generated destructor stub
}

void identificator::setID(int i)
{
    id=i;
}

int identificator::getID()
{
    return id;
}

void identificator::printID()
{
    for(;;)
    {
        printf("%d\n",this->getID());
    }
    emit finished();
}
```

а вот main.cpp:

```
#include <QtCore>
#include <QCoreApplication>
#include <QApplication>
#include "myThread.h"
#include "identificator.h"
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QCoreApplication a(argc, argv);
    printf("Hello\n");
    identificator *first=new identificator();
    identificator *second=new identificator();
    QThread *thread1=new QThread;
    QThread *thread2=new QThread;
    first->setID(3);
    second->setID(4);
    QObject::connect(thread1, SIGNAL(started()), first, SLOT(printID()));
    QObject::connect(thread2, SIGNAL(started()), second, SLOT(printID()));
    QObject::connect(first, SIGNAL(finished()), thread1, SLOT(quit()));
    QObject::connect(second, SIGNAL(finished()), thread2, SLOT(quit()));
    thread1->start();
    thread2->start();
    return a.exec();
}
```

Ожидаю, что в консоль будет выводится числа 3 и 4, вразнобой,бесконечно долго, но при запуске в консоль выводится только 3.
Очень прошу, объясните мне пожалуйста, как добиться их параллельной работы?
Заранее спасибо!

---

Вычитал, что алгоритм должен быть примерно такой:

1. Создание потока.
2. Создание объекта и перенос в поток.
3. Установка сигнально слотовых связей.
4. Запуск потока с заданным приориетом.

Поэтому добавил, как посоветовали: moveToThread()

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QCoreApplication a(argc, argv);
    printf("Hello\n");
    identificator *first=new identificator();
    identificator *second=new identificator();
    QThread *thread1=new QThread;
    QThread *thread2=new QThread;
    first->setID(3);
    second->setID(4);
    first->moveToThread(thread1);
    second->moveToThread(thread2);
    QObject::connect(thread1, SIGNAL(started()), first, SLOT(printID()));
    QObject::connect(thread2, SIGNAL(started()), second, SLOT(printID()));
    QObject::connect(first, SIGNAL(finished()), thread1, SLOT(quit()));
    QObject::connect(second, SIGNAL(finished()), thread2, SLOT(quit()));
    thread1->start();
    thread2->start();
    return a.exec();
}
```

Добавил moveToThread() и после инициализации и после connect() оба варианта не помогли....

Буду благодарен за помощь.

Comment: А где вы привязываете свой identificator к QThread?

Comment: в main.cpp, через функцию connect(), или нужно внутри класса делать привязку к потоку?

Comment: А, точно, не увидел...

Comment: http://www.evileg.ru/baza-znanij/qt/qthread-sozdanie-potokov-v-qt.html попробовал этот пример реализовать, все получилось, поправил вместо функции QDebug - printf - работать перестало, может дело в ней....

Comment: Да, printf вроде непотокобезопасен...

Comment: Исправил в моей программе printf на QDebug, проблема таже, выводится только одно число

Comment: @infernalcucumber [main.cpp](http://pastebin.com/mneNHA9e) [idprinter.h](http://pastebin.com/ts0M3w3a)

Comment: @yrHeTaTeJlb Я скомпилировал Ваш вариант, проблема та же - в консоль выводится только 3. У Вас другой вывод?

Comment: @infernalcucumber, у меня чередуются 3 и 4. Хотя надо сказать дома и на работе это выглядит по-разному. Дома – 33434434343343, на работе – 3333333444444433333

Comment: Я через eclipse и QTCreator собрал Ваши исходники main.cpp idprinter.h , запустил на двух машинах и везде в потоке одно число отображается.

Comment: Однако, работает. На Qt 5.5

Answer (score 1):

После коннектов попробуйте добавить

```
first->moveToThread(thread1);
second->moveToThread(thread2);
```

Однако я рекомендую посмотреть в сторону `QtConcurrent::run()`. Это штука более высокого уровня, может с ней будет малость проще на первых порах. Так же есть `QRunnable` + `QThreadPool`, которые для некоторых задач могут быть удобнее чем `QThread`.

Как используется `Qthread` лучше всего посмотреть в справке, там очень доступно все описано. Если в двух словах, то нужно создать класс, слот которого будет выполнятся в отдельном потоке(в документации его назвали `Worker`). Потом объект этого класса помещается в поток(`worker->moveToThread(&workerThread);`). И когда какой-нибудь сигнал активирует слот нашего `worker`-а, то этот слот выполнится в отдельном потоке.

Comment: Добавил moveToThread(), не помогло... Попробовал вариант с QtConcurrent::run() - тоже, блокируются все потоки после запуска первого...

Comment: @infernalcucumber, а если создать QThreadPool и вызвать maxThreadCount, что получится?

Comment: QThreadPool тоже почему то аналогично работает - выполняется сперва функция первого потока, потом второго, т.е. последовательно

Comment: @infernalcucumber, maxThreadCount что возвращает?

Comment: [ссылка](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/thread-basics.html) - попробовал оттуда вызвать `maxThreadCount()` перед `start`. В консоль выводится : "1".

Comment: @infernalcucumber, maxThreadCount использует `QThread::idealThreadCount ()`. Это число зависит от количества ядер процессора, реальных и логических. Попробуйте в примере с пулом потоков сделать так `threadPool->setMaxThreadCount(2)`